# iOS > possible play a partially downloaded video?

Tags: ios, video, asihttprequest

Say we are downloading a large video - its 50Mb - but only 25Mb has downloaded so far - is it possible to start playing the video before its completely downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you are using MPMoviePlayerController for your video...

MPMoviePlayerController has a loadState property that you can monitor with [this notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayerloadstatedidchangenotification). Check to see if the video has been downloaded to a *playable extent* and then play.

```
//Begin observing the moviePlayer's load state.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];


- (void)moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //NSLog(@"State changed to: %d\n", moviePlayer.loadState);
    if(moviePlayer.loadState == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable && [videoIndicator isAnimating]){
        //if load state is ready to play
        [videoIndicator stopAnimating];//Pause and hide the indicator
        [self.contentView addSubview:[moviePlayer view]];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
        [moviePlayer play];//play the video
    }

}
```

And this is very important: If you are trying to download a video more than 10 ten minutes long, you will need to use [HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/).

Comment: I am loading videos with ASIHTTPRequest, not with MPMoviePlayerController. Possible to start playing it until it is fully loaded?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any experience with ASIHTTPRequest. I will do some searching but I can't guarantee I will find anything that you haven't already.